# Switching players

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm made a program that calculates the current health of a player and switches between them. I need help switching between players. This is what i have so far:

```
class Player():

    def turn(life):
        players = ['Player 1', 'Player 2']
        life = 100
        for player in players:
            while life >= 0:
                print (life)
                print ("+, -, or end turn")
                choice = input("> ")

                if choice == "+":
                    print ("Damage taken")
                    healing = int(input("> "))
                    life += healing
                elif choice == "-":
                    print ("Damage taken")
                    damage = int(input("> "))
                    life -= damage
                elif choice == "end turn" or "end":
                    return

            else:
                print ("You lose!")

play = Player()
play.turn()
```

Comment: You seem to misunderstand classes. Please reread or continue the tutorial.

Comment: Why does a `Player` contain two `players`? And why do two `players` only have one `life`?

Comment: You appear to have defined a class that is more suitable for the game, not for a player.  The game class could certainly maintain the list of players and also have a variable `currentPlayer` that kept track of who the current player was, but these variables should be class member variables (initialized in `__init__` for example) and not declared inside `turn()`.

Comment: This question needs more help than we can provide. We like helping people, but sometimes you need to help yourself first by reading a book on the language, the on-line documentation, or asking someone you know. Once you understand the topic a little better, we invite you to edit this question, fix the obvious mistakes, and get it re-opened.

Answer (score 2):

I've been in a similar position before. I would recommend doing something a bit different than the answer you might be looking for. Instead of looking for a solution to this individual problem, I would recommend looking at resources for game design patterns.

While I think that the learning curve might be a bit high initially, I think that if you learn to work with proper design patterns for game mechanics, you will find it much easier to build what you are after.

There are a few different resources that you can choose from. I used http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/ (I have no association with this individual), but I also have a background in c++. I would look around for what might be the most intuitive for you and give it a try.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, health=100):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health

    def hit(self, n):
        assert n >= 0
        self.health -= n

    def heal(self, n):
        assert n >= 0
        self.health += n

    @property
    def is_dead(self):
        return self.health <= 0

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.players = [Player("Adam"), Player("Bert")]

    def turn(self, me, him):
        # fill this in!

    def play(self):
        a, b = self.players
        while True:
            self.turn(a, b)
            if b.is_dead:
                print("{} won!".format(a.name))
                break
            else:
                # swap players
                a, b = b, a

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game().play()
```